# Refactor-rename (alt+shift+r) is not working in android adt

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

[image]I am using android adt with android SDK tools 22.3. Refactor-rename is not working through keys(alt+shift+r),but it works if I use mouse right click-->refactor-->rename.
How to enable (alt+shift+r) for Refactor-rename?

Comment: Check whether the shortcut is set or not: Window-Preference-General-Keys. Type "rename" and check for "Rename - Refactoring" for category "Refactor - Java"

Comment: The short cut is set. I will attach the screen shot with my question

Comment: For me the shortcut was set but attempting to refresh the binding I realized I can't type Shift+Alt+R, it will be displayed as either Shift+R or Alt+R. (Linux Mint 19.2, Eclipe 2020-06, Cinnamon)

Comment: ...Then I remembered Alt+Shift is the shortcut for switching  keyboard layout, and unlike under Windows, in Linux Mint/Cinnamon it does not work simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window->Preference->General->Keys and changes Your shortcut in the java file![image: image for sample]

Comment: I have edited my question and attached the screen shot